# Is there an option to prevent Google Chrome from closing tab on center click?

Tags: google-chrome

When I use my laptop, the center click and the left click are somewhat in a blurry area, which causes Google Chrome to close tabs when I try to select them. It's utterly annoying, and I have lost many unfinished commands and other navigation because of this.

Is there a way to disable this annoying feature and *not* close tabs on center click?

Answer (score 0):

You can do Ctrl + shift + T to reopen the last tab with all the navigations but you will still lose written data.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of re-opening tabs. That's not the issue. I want to prevent Chrome from closing tabs without warning when I do not click on the close button.